# Does `ulab.numpy` support calculating results into a given array? (like the `out` argument in numpy)

Tags: numpy, micropython, ulab

I'm running MicroPython code on an ESP32 using ulab. I have a 2D array of multiple audio channels that I constantly read from files. I'm using I2S to play a mix of those channels, let's assume mixing is done with `np.mean()`.

My code generally looks like this:

```
channels_data = np.zeros((num_channels, channel_size))
while True:
  for i, c in enumerate(audio_channels):
    _read_channel_into(c, channels_data[i])
  mixed_data = np.mean(channels_data, axis=0)  # <- Creates a new array every time.
  _send_to_i2s(mixed_data)
```

At every iteration, `np.mean()` creates a new array in memory for the result. This array is then gets copied to the I2S buffer and then thrown away. I couldn't find support for a `out=` argument, like numpy has. I sometimes get MemoryError when MicroPython tried to allocate this buffer.

Is there any other solution to avoid the array creation at every iteration?
(other than solutions like reducing the buffer size, forcing GC, or removing other tasks that run in parallel, ...)